# Is there any way to get the latest S3 file by GCP StorageTransfer?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-composer

We're running Airflow/Composer on GCP and trying to get the latest S3 file by any python operator. Currently we're getting S3 file once a day, they can happen to export several files in the same day but we'd like to get only the latest one.

Are there any options to achieve this?

Here's current script:

```
create_transfer_job = CloudDataTransferServiceCreateJobOperator(
                task_id="create_transfer_job",
                body=self.create_transfer_body(self),
                aws_conn_id=aws_conn_id(),
                on_success_callback=partial(self.write_logging_url, 
                  self.get_tmp_project_id()),
            )

   
def create_transfer_body(self):
       
        dag_parameters = get_dag_parameters()
        data_transfer = dag_parameters["data_transfer"]
        s3_data_source = data_transfer["awsS3DataSource"]

        s3_data_source_path = ""
        if "path" in s3_data_source:
            s3_data_source_path = s3_data_source["path"]

        # check
        print("s3_data_source_path!:"+s3_data_source_path)

        file_types = file_types()
        includePrefixes = []
        for file_type in file_types:
            includePrefixes.append(f"{file_type}/")

        objectConditions = {
            "includePrefixes": includePrefixes
            ,"lastModifiedSince": "{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='initialize', key='last_modified_since') }}
            ,"lastModifiedBefore": "{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='initialize', key='last_modified_before') }}
        }
        if "objectConditions" in data_transfer:
            objectConditions = data_transfer["objectConditions"]

        transfer_body = {
            "description": "DataPipe Data Transfer",
            "status": GcpTransferJobsStatus.ENABLED,
            "projectId": project_id(),
            "name": "transferJobs/dataPipelineJob_" + str(uuid.uuid4()),
            "schedule": {
                "scheduleStartDate": datetime.today(),
                "scheduleEndDate": datetime.today(),
            },
            "transferSpec": {
                "awsS3DataSource": {"bucketName": s3_data_source["bucketName"], "path": s3_data_source_path},
                "gcsDataSink": {"bucketName": self.get_gcs_bucket_name()},
                "objectConditions": objectConditions,
                "transfer_options": {
                    "deleteObjectsFromSourceAfterTransfer": False,
                    "overwriteWhen": "{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='initialize', key='overwrite_when') }}",
                },
            },
            "loggingConfig": {
                "logActions": ["FIND", "DELETE", "COPY"],
                "logActionStates": ["FAILED"],
            },
        }
        return create_transfer_body
```

Comment: Did you enable Cloud Storage object versioning? What do you mean by the latest version? Cloud Storage only delivers the latest version of an object except if you specify the version.

Comment: @John Hanley Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately it's not versioning, S3 files are exported with timestamp like XXXX_master_20231208034500.csv. If you have any recommendation, I'd be appreciate your further comment. Anyway, thank you so much!

Comment: If you are using your own versioning scheme, then you will need to parse the object list in your code. I don't have a suggestion for doing that with Composer.